# R: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' for Quadratic Discriminant Analysis on IRIS data (creation of table)

Tags: r, sorting, classification

I'm doing classification on IRIS data using Quadratic Discriminant analysis in R, I'm getting error at creation of table i.e "Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' Have you called 'sort' on a list?" how to solve this error? What variable should i unlist here??

```
>  library(MASS)  

> #Build the model 

> model4<-qda(class~SepalLength+SepalWidth+PetalLength+PetalWidth,data=iris_eval)

>#Summarize the model 

>summary(model4) 

>#Predict using the model 

>iris_eval$pred_qda<-predict(model4,x) 

>#Accuracy of the model 

>mtab3<-table(iris_eval$pred_qda,iris_eval$class) 

#here that error is coming

>confusionMatrix(mtab3)
```

Comment: We cannot actually run your code because of  `iris_eval`.   How was that generated?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582505/r-x-must-be-atomic-for-sort-list/36582851#36582851) looks pretty similar.

Comment: iris_eval is a .csv file of original iris data

Comment: but i didn't get my answer from that post..

Comment: `Loading Data
> iris_eval <- read.csv("D:/iris.txt", header=FALSE)

> colnames(iris_eval)<-c("SepalLength","SepalWidth","PetalLength","PetalWidth","class")
 
> head(iris_eval)`

Comment: what variable should i unlist ? @Imo

Comment: From the linked post, the table object you are feeding the confusion matrix must be causing the problem. Try casting it to a matrix using `as.matrix`, like `confusionMatrix(as.matrix(mtab3))`.

Comment: but the table itself not created, so mtab3 could not found error is getting @Imo

Comment: @Imo I tried like this from your post : mtab3<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(wine_eval$pred_qda,wine_eval$class))) and mtab3 was successfully created but typing this: confusionMatrix(as.matrix(mtab3)) I'm getting new error called :Error in is.factor(reference) : 
  argument "reference" is missing, with no default