# Rstudio Columns Multiple Binary Features

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-engineering

I want to split a column in multiple binary dummy columns. my dataframe: df

```
id siz eage    
1 6 10    
2 7 11    
3 8 10
```

At the moment i have this code with package qdaptools and caret:

```
df <- cbind(df [1:3],mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$age), ':')))
```

My question: how can I give a title to these dummy columns, so I get this:

```
id size age_10 age_11    
1 6 1 0    
2 7 0 1    
3 8 1 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `dummy.data.frame` from `dummies` package.

```r
library(dummies)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dummy.data.frame(names="age", sep="_")
```

**Output is:**

```
  id size age_10 age_11
1  1    6      1      0
2  2    7      0      1
3  3    8      1      0
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, size = 6:8, age = c(10L, 11L, 10L)), .Names = c("id", 
"size", "age"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**Update:**
For the error which you are getting on your actual data you can use below code

> Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' Have you
>   called 'sort' on a list?

```
library(dummies)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  dummy.data.frame(names="Verkoopkanaal_groepering", sep="_")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but now i've got a new problem/error: 

Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

How can i tackle this one?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582505/error-x-must-be-atomic-for-sort-list) help? If not then you may need to provide sample data along with code which generates this error and the best bet would be a new post.

Comment: yes, but where do i have to use unlist in this code?
df_new <- cbind(subset(df, select = -c(Sell)), dummy(c("Sell"), data=df, sep="_"))

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: Is pastebin allright for you (i had too many characters).
https://pastebin.com/ak2M4imq

Answer (score 0):

To rename by index:  `colnames(df)[4:5] <- c("age_10", "age_11")`
To rename by existing column name `colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "INSERT_COL_NAME"] <- "NEW_COL_NAME"`